# Is it safe to alias rm to safe-rm?

Tags: bash, filesystem, security, alias, rm

We are happy to use `safe-rm` as a replacement to `rm`, but is it considered safe to alias it?

e.g.

```
alias rm='safe-rm'
```

Answer (score 4):

Yes, an alias is just a shell-only rename. The scope of an alias is only the shell that you are currently in. `safe-rm` is just a wrapper that does some blacklist checking to prune the arguments list, it still calls `rm` under the hood (it also calls `rm` explicitly with `/bin/rm` so the alias does not affect the script)

It is not, however, safe in that it does not prevent a user from using `rm` explicitly either by unsetting the alias or by explicitly calling `/bin/rm`. safe-rm is only to prevent accidents, not a security feature, this is what permissions are for. You can still easily delete blacklisted files if you actually want to do that.

Answer (score 1):

---

### This is an extra tip

To avoid a mistaken `rm -rf`, do not type `rm -rf`.

- If necessary, change to the parent of the directory you want to delete.
- `mv directory-to-delete DELETE`
- Explore `DELETE` and check that it is indeed what you wanted to delete
- `rm -rf DELETE`

Never call `rm -rf` with an argument other than `DELETE`. Doing the deletion in several stages gives you an opportunity to verify that you aren't deleting the wrong thing, either because of a typo (as in `rm -rf /foo /bar` instead of `rm -rf /foo/bar`) or because of a braino (oops, no, I meant to delete `foo.old` and keep `foo.new`).

If your problem is that you can't trust others not to type `rm -rf`, consider removing their admin privileges. There's a lot more that can go wrong than `rm`.

Let me get into the problem you asked

This tool, [safe-rm](https://launchpad.net/safe-rm), ships with a default system-wide configuration file (/etc/safe-rm.conf), but each user can supplement that list of "protected" directories and files by adding lines to ~/.safe-rm.

Use `\rm` when you are sure about what you are deleting but most of the time, I prefer to go through the confirmation. Too many files disappeared because of a rushed removal action.