# Make alias with completed command

Tags: command-line, alias

I hate `rm -rf /*`, so I want to echo something instead of running `rm -rf /*`.
How can I make this possible?

Comment: There is a great answer to this on Serverfault: https://serverfault.com/a/337098/390909

Comment: Related: https://askubuntu.com/q/477925/631600

Answer (score 2):

By "hate", I presume that you mean that you are afraid of accidentally running this?

The command `rm -r /` (with or without `-f`) will prompt you:

```
rm: it is dangerous to operate recursively on `/'
rm: use --no-preserve-root to override this failsafe
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't check this when you specify `/*`, because the latter is expanded into each folder. While most folders and their contents will be safe (because you haven't used `sudo`), unfortunately those inside your home folder will be deleted.

There is no simple answer to this. You could write a function in `.bashrc` that checks for this, but it would be quite complex: the function would have to:

- Check the options as to whether they contained `-r`, `-R` or `--recursive` and whether or not you used `--no-preserve-root`.
- Look at the non-option parameters to find out if it is likely that you used `/*`.

I think that `-f` or `--force` can be ignored, because without this, the command still has the ability to wreak havoc.

I have written a script to do exactly this. It is below. Simply add this to the end of your file `~/.bashrc`, **close all open terminals** and re-open the terminal, and it should work.

Warning, *Warning*, WARNING, **WARNING**!

1. Please **test thoroughly** before using it live.
2. I have put `echo` before the actual `rm` command in the script (right at the end), to allow you to test. This means that when you run it, it will display the command instead of actually running it. When you've tested it thoroughly, edit your `~/.bashrc` to remove the word `echo`.
3. This applies to **your** terminal. It does **not** apply to root's, i.e. sudo. Thus, it will **still cause havoc** if you run `sudo rm -rf /*`. To make it apply to sudo… well, there must be a way, but sorry, I don't know how. `:(` I'm sure someone clever here will figure it out, in which case I can add it to this reply. (There is a way if you can guarantee that sudo will always use the same `${PATH}`, but I don't think that this is true.)

Here is the script:

```
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#    Amendment to rm
#
#    Check if it is likely that the user called rm on root with recursion but without the option
#    --no-preserve-root
#    If so, display a warning. Otherwise, allow rm to continue unhindered.
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


function rm ()
{
    # Extract all of the options and parameters.
    local -r GETOPT="$( getopt --longoptions=force,interactive::,one-file-system,no-preserve-root,recursive,dir,verbose,help,version    \
                               --options=fiIrRdv -- "${@}"
                      )"

    # Replace the current parameters with the interpreted ones from rm.
    eval set -- "${GETOPT}"

    # Define variables to use in the function.
    local -i FILES_COUNT=0                              # The number of files and folders found.
    local ALL_ROOT=true                                 # Assume true unless found otherwise.
    local RECURSIVE_USED=false                          # Unless found true.
    local NO_PRESERVE_ROOT_USED=false                   # Unless found true.
    local PARAM                                         # To hold the parameter being inspected.
    local INTERACTIVE_STATE=false                       # Whether we are expecting an option to --interactive.

    # Run through the parameters to find if we should catch this command.
    for PARAM
    do
        # Handle the option --interactive first.
        if ${INTERACTIVE_STATE}
        then
            INTERACTIVE_STATE=false                     # Turn off the interactive state.

        elif [[ ${PARAM} == '--interactive' ]]
        then
            INTERACTIVE_STATE=true

        elif [[ ${PARAM} == '-r' || ${PARAM} == '-R' || ${PARAM} == '--recursive' ]]
        then
            RECURSIVE_USED=true

        elif [[ ${PARAM} == '--no-preserve-root' ]]
        then
            NO_PRESERVE_ROOT_USED=true

        elif [[ ${PARAM} =~ ^- ]]
        then
             :                                          # Ignore any option that we don't care about.                          

        else
            : $(( ++FILES_COUNT ))                      # Keep count.
            if ! [[ ${PARAM} =~ ^/ ]]
            then
                 ALL_ROOT=false                         # This isn't a root file or folder.
            fi
        fi
    done

    # Is this likely to be the command that we are searching for?
    if (( FILES_COUNT > 0 )) && ${RECURSIVE_USED} && ${ALL_ROOT} && ! ${NO_PRESERVE_ROOT_USED}
    then
        # Yes! Recursive; all root files and folders; and missing no-preserve-root.
        # Leave a message and exit with an error.
        echo 'You are using rm to remove all root files and folders.'         >&2
        echo 'Please use --no-preserve-root if that is really what you want.' >&2
        return 3
    fi

    # No, this is (supposedly) safe. Run the command.
    echo rm "${@}"

} # rm
```

Comment: Hi Paddy, would using `-i` help? `man rm` has `-i     prompt before every removal`.

Comment: @DKBose That's quite a good idea. You can create an alias in your `~/.bashrc`, as `alias rm='rm --interactive'`. Unfortunately, the warning regarding sudo still holds. I don't know a reliable way around this.